# Not able to Stop communication port in serial communication

Tags: c#

I have tried everything but not able to stop serial communication once i start it and communication gets established.

> > Start Method to send data

```
public void Start(List<byte> RGBdata)
{           
    if (!m_port.IsOpen)
    {
        m_port.Open();
    }           
    do
    {
        Break();
        Thread.Sleep( 5 );

        m_port.Write( new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 1 );
        SendData(RGBdata);
        Thread.Sleep( 1);
    }
    while (true);
}
```

> > Stop to stop communication

```
public void Stop()
{
    m_port.Close();

    if (m_port.IsOpen)
    {
        m_port.Close();
        m_port.Dispose();
    }
}
```

What I think is as while (true) loop continuous works , I am not able to stop com port. How do I achieve it.

I have used stop flag ,dispose but nothing works. Can anyone tell me what wrong i am doing or is it i need to use particular scope in which i need to open and close communication i.e using()

Answer (score 0):

How do you access your Stop() ?

I tried the following example, worked like expected:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SerialPort Port = new SerialPort("COM21", 9600);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (!Port.IsOpen)
            {
                Port.Open();
            }
            do
            {
                if (Port.IsOpen == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("CLOSED!!!");
                    break;
                }
                Port.Write(new byte[] { 0 }, 0, 1);
            }
            while (true);
        });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Port.Close();
    }
}
```

Port is getting closed after clicking the button.